# Django query Unicode Issues

Tags: django, postgresql, python-3.x, unicode

### **EDIT #2:**

```
{'sql': 'SELECT "strains_terpene"."id", "strains_terpene"."name", 
"strains_terpene"."short_desc", "strains_terpene"."long_desc", 
"strains_terpene"."aroma", "strains_terpene"."flavor", 
"strains_terpene"."effects" FROM "strains_terpene" WHERE     
"strains_terpene"."name" = \'\xce±-Humulene\'', 'time': '0.000'}
```

Upon closer look it appears that django may be properly escaping the single quotes in the end. Had to take a different angle to see this by using this:

```
from django.db import connections
connections['default'].queries
```

***So now the question remains, why even though python3, django, and postgres are all set to utf-8 is the unicode being encoded to local in the query?***

## **Original Question:**

Here is the runtime error:

```
strains.models.DoesNotExist: Terpene matching query does not exist.
```

Here is the `str(Terpene.objects.filter(name='β-Caryophyllene').query)`:

```
SELECT "strains_terpene"."id", "strains_terpene"."name", "strains_terpene"."short_desc", "strains_terpene"."long_desc", "strains_terpene"."aroma", "strains_terpene"."flavor", "strains_terpene"."effects" 
FROM "strains_terpene" 
WHERE "strains_terpene"."name" = ß-Caryophyllene
```

Here is how postgres likes to see the query for it to work:

```
select * from strains_terpene where name = 'β-Caryophyllene'
```

Am i missing something here? Why is Django not wrapping my condition in single quotes?

- PostgresDB is encoded with utf-8
- Python 3 strings are unicode

### **EDIT:**

I notice the query attribute is also converting the β to ß...

I thought this could be a conversion issue considering im using windows cmd for the python shell.

So i did a:

```
with open('log2.txt','w',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    print(Terpene.objects.filter(name='β-Caryophyllene').query, file=f)
```

And here are the results even when output directly to utf-8 plain text.

```
SELECT "strains_terpene"."id", "strains_terpene"."name", "strains_terpene"."short_desc", "strains_terpene"."long_desc", "strains_terpene"."aroma", "strains_terpene"."flavor", "strains_terpene"."effects" 
FROM "strains_terpene" 
WHERE "strains_terpene"."name" = ß-Caryophyllene
```

So now I am confused on 2 fronts. Why does django choose to ommit the single quotes for the where condition and why is the lowercase beta being converted to an uppercase?

#### **EXTRA INFO:**

Here is the section of actual code.

- Importing mass results via CSV.
- The results dict stores the mapping between columns and Terpene Names
- The first log.txt is for verifying the contents of results
- The second log1.txt is to verify the key before using it as the lookup condition
- The finally log2.txt verifies sql being sent to the database

First the Code Snippet:

```
results = {
            u'α-Pinene': row[7],
            u'β-Pinene': row[8],
            u'Terpinolene': row[9],
            u'Geraniol': row[10],
            u'α-Terpinene': row[11],
            u'γ-Terpinene': row[12],
            u'Camphene': row[13],
            u'Linalool': row[14],
            u'd-Limonene': row[15],
            u'Citral': row[16],
            u'Myrcene': row[17],
            u'α-Terpineol': row[18],
            u'Citronellol': row[19],
            u'dl-Menthol': row[20],
            u'1-Borneol': row[21],
            u'2-Piperidone': row[22],
            u'β-Caryophyllene': row[23],
            u'α-Humulene': row[24],
            u'Caryophyllene Oxide': row[25],
        }
        with open("log.txt", "w") as text_file:
            print(results.keys(), file=text_file)
        for r, v in results.items():
            if '<' not in v:
                value = float(v.replace("%", ""))
                with open("log1.txt", "w") as text2:
                    print(r, file=text2)
                with open("log2.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as text3:
                    print(Terpene.objects.filter(name=r).query, file=text3)
                TerpeneResult.objects.create(
                    terpene=Terpene.objects.get(name=r),
                    qa_sample=sample,
                    result=value,
                )
```

**And log.txt**  -- results.keys():

```
dict_keys(['dl-Menthol', 'Geraniol', 'Camphene', '1-Borneol', 'Linalool', 
'α-Humulene', 'Caryophyllene Oxide', 'β-Caryophyllene', 'Citronellol', 
'α-Pinene', '2-Piperidone', 'β-Pinene', 'd-Limonene', 'γ-Terpinene',  
'Terpinolene', 'α-Terpineol', 'Myrcene', 'α-Terpinene', 'Citral'])
```

**log1.txt** -- `α-Humulene`

Lastly the sql being generated -- **log2.txt**:

```
SELECT "strains_terpene"."id", "strains_terpene"."name", "strains_terpene"."short_desc", "strains_terpene"."long_desc", "strains_terpene"."aroma", "strains_terpene"."flavor", "strains_terpene"."effects" 
FROM "strains_terpene" 
WHERE "strains_terpene"."name" = Î±-Humulene
```

Note the unicode being lost at the last moment when the sql is generated.

Comment: In log2.txt, The Unicode is not lost, but displayed incorrectly.  `Î±-Humulene` is UTF-8-encoded `α-Humulene` displayed with `Windows-1252`.  This is typical when viewing a UTF-8 file on Windows Notepad and other Windows editors if a byte order mark (BOM, U+FEFF) is not encoded at the beginning of a UTF-8 file.  Windows assumes a localized encoding otherwise.  Use `utf-8-sig` to write the file instead.

Comment: Even with BOM added the unicode greek is still be displayed with `Windows-1252`. ST3 `view.encoding()` verifies `UTF-8 with BOM`

Comment: How are you viewing the file?  Try with and without BOM with Notepad, for example.  It's still a viewing problem, not a string-generation problem.  Or use Notepad++, which you can force display in the encoding of your choice.

Comment: What is the encoding of the first two log files since it is unspecified?

Comment: I am viewing in Sublime Text 3 as UTF-8 with BOM. That being said, why are the first two instances of `r` -which contains greek unicode - encoding and displaying into the logs just fine?

When asked to write the whole dictionary contents to file, even without BOM, the unicode is written properly. When asked to iterate through the key value pairs and write the value of the current key to file - it does so fine.

However, when passing the the unicode dict key as the string argument to the queryset field lookup - it looks as if the sql string is being generated in `Windows-1252`.

Comment: By default the encoding is `UTF-8` and this is verified in sublime text via view.encoding(). I am only explicitly delcaring unicode strings for the dict keys and `utf-8-sig` for testing purposes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102164/discussion-between-mark-tolonen-and-n-balauro).